# QTabWidget:winId cannot select tabs

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTabWidget and everything is working properly.
But when I try to call winId with my QTabWidget object it's working, though I can't select any tabs. I'm already calling setTabEnabled and it's still not working.
The strange thing is when I am adding a new tab into my QTabWidget everything is working fine.
Do you eventually know whats going on? :confused:

Comment: We'd have a better idea of your problem if you add the snippet of code in question.

Comment: The version of Qt you're using might be helpful as well, in addition to the platform.